# Python C API: How to evaluate custom object for boolean?

Tags: python, c, api, boolean

I found a strange situation in the Python C API.

I have a custom python object and when it is evaluated with the bool built-in function, his return is False.

How to make a type of custom object be evaluated to True ?

[Declaration of the object](https://github.com/bastibe/lunatic-python/blob/master/src/luainpython.c#L370)

I noticed the problem when I try to evaluate a function (a custom object representing a function) as follows:

```
if cutomobject: # False! But the object is a valid reference.
```

[The thread module makes this check, and this prevents me of execute thread](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Lib/threading.py#L476)

Answer (score 0):

As usual I have not understood my question

But the correct answer is here:

[c.tp_as_mapping](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#c.tp_as_mapping)

```
static PyMappingMethods LuaObject_as_mapping = {
#if PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x02050000
    (lenfunc)LuaObject_length,    /*mp_length*/
#else
(inquiry)LuaObject_length,    /*mp_length*/
#endif
    (binaryfunc)LuaObject_subscript,/*mp_subscript*/
    (objobjargproc)LuaObject_ass_subscript,/*mp_ass_subscript*/
};
```

```